# How to query points that fall outside their designated regions?

Tags: polygon, spatial-analyst, query, data-quality

I have a shapefile with 250 points. Each point has a `region` attribute. In another shapefile I have all the possible regions with their names (it is polyline geometry).

Unfortunately the coordinates of the points are sometimes wrong.

I would like to query which points don't lie in the region specified by their `region` attribute.

Comment: Polylines don't represent regions, can you convert them to polygons? Also what GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with ArcGIS? You could do a join of the 2 layers, then see which points dont have a coresponding region.

Another way would be to simply do an overlay of points over regions and again see which points   are unchanged.

Oh, missed the part where you had polylines. You should convert these to polygons first!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a point layer with region column  and polygonal region layer, in qgis you can use `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union` to merge point data and polygonal data then use SPIT tool to move your new merged file to postgis and you can do what you want.

[image]

if you want delete point which isnt in your region, you can use:

```
DELETE FROM point_poly_merged
       WHERE region <> pre_defined_region;
```

i hope it helps you....